# How to zip several undefined different lenght lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to write a function that get a list of lists with different length  as input and return the zipped result.
What I am looking for is that to expand my code below to any amount of lists. (I cannot use Zip Longest function since I am trying to do this on our system that does not have most of python functions including
zip longest function)

Here is my code:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9]]

def myzip(a):
    temp1=[]
    temp2=[]
    temp3=[]
    lens=[]
    t=1
    for i in a:
        if(t==1):
            temp1=i
            lens.append(len(temp1))
            t+=1
        elif(t==2):
            temp2=i
            lens.append(len(temp2))
            t+=1
        elif(t==3):
            temp3=i
            lens.append(len(temp3))
        
    for i in range(max(lens)):
        if(i<len(temp1)):
            print(temp1[i])
        if(i<len(temp2)):
            print(temp2[i])
        if(i<len(temp3)):
            print(temp3[i])
        
        
    
myzip(a)
```

Output:

```
1
5
7
2
6
8
3
9
4
```

This function works only for 3 lists because I am using Temp lists in order to achieve the zipped result But I want to make this code works for any number of lists. for example I able to run for `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9],[11,33]]` or `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6]]` or `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9],...,[25,22]]`

Comment: Scroll down to the Round Robin recipe here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes

Comment: If your Python version does not even have itertools - what does it have? Can you please clarify your requirements, i.e. what features can and cannot be used? Do you have builtins? Do the syntactical features like generators work?

Comment: The documentation for `itertools.zip_longest` includes a pure Python implementation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [11, 33]]

for item in [x for t in zip_longest(*lists) for x in t]:
    if item is not None:
        print(item)
```

Output:

```
1
5
7
11
2
6
8
33
3
9
4
```

Or to just get them as a list:

```
items = [x for t in zip_longest(*lists) for x in t if x is not None]
```

Note: @MarkM made a worthwhile remark - if your source data contains `None`, this approach will have a problem in that it will filter them out. You should tell `zip_longest` to use a different `fillvalue` in that case, that does not show up in your data. For example:

```
items = [x for t in zip_longest(*lists, fillvalue='') for x in t if x is not None]
```

If you cannot import `itertools` for very specific reasons (as mentioned in the comments), you could just use the implementation shown in the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
def repeat(object, times=None):
    if times is None:
        while True:
            yield object
    else:
        for i in range(times):
            yield object


def zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=None):
    iterators = [iter(it) for it in args]
    num_active = len(iterators)
    if not num_active:
        return
    while True:
        values = []
        for i, it in enumerate(iterators):
            try:
                value = next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                num_active -= 1
                if not num_active:
                    return
                iterators[i] = repeat(fillvalue)
                value = fillvalue
            values.append(value)
        yield tuple(values)
```

Comment: Perhaps the caveat that `None` shouldn't be in the original lists is worth mentioning (the published itertools recipe handles `None` in the input without issue)

Comment: Of course you can wrap the above in a function as well, it's generally a better idea to create a function that returns the result you want and then print that (or print parts of it), instead of having a function that prints values itself, which reduces its general usability.

Comment: Yes, so that was what I wanted to do. I wanted to implement zip_longest but since we are not using python directly, I cannot use the function. I have to implement it

Comment: What do you mean exactly by " we are not using Python directly?" @Nataliya - are you looking for a solution that uses no imports whatsoever for some reason?

Comment: I can import lots of things like numpy but since we are using something call Scriptcase, zip_longest won't be compatible with it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could also work for you:

```
def flatten_list(my_list):
    flat_list = []
    for element in my_list:
        if type(element) is list: #if element is a list, iterate through it 
            for item in element:
                flat_list.append(item)
        else:
            flat_list.append(element)
    return flat_list

nested_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10],[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[4,6,7,8]]
print('Original List', nested_list)
print('Flat List', flatten_list(nested_list))
```

**Output**

```
Original List [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [4, 6, 7, 8]]
Flat List [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8]
```